# Error unlocking /dev/sda5: Failed to activate device: operation not permitted (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: boot, encryption, gparted, luks, udisks

I've had a booting problem on a Dell Latitude for a long time now that I've left aside but now want to give another try to access. It's an Ubuntu 18.04 encrypted with LUKS, which used to work properly. One day, upon booting, i got following error in a CLI environment:

> [    1.207067] firewire_ohci 0000:09:00.0: register access failure
>   Please enter passphrase for disk SAMSUNG_ssd_830_Series (sda5_crypt)!<

I can then enter input for password which shows up as ***. I know the password, but I can not enter it. Pressing enter simply brings me to the next line, and then the last phrase (Please enter passphrase for disk SAMSUNG_ssd_830_Series (sda5_crypt)!) pops up again.

I can't recall exactly what I did on the last successful session before getting this, but with hope of someday being able to access the data stored on the disc, I let it be and got an external SSD to use for the time being, leaving the internal disc with the error for later. I also encrypted the externad SSD (LUKS) but one day I got the same error (although slightly different) on the new one, and I still have it after a year of so.

On the external SSD, the difference is that I actually do get to the LUKS encryption heading, where I can enter my password normally (not in CLI but as its meant to) and it works. But then, I get to CLI again with error:

> [    1.908518] firewire_ohci 0000:09:00.0: register access failure
>   BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
>   Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>   (initramfs)<

It seems here, it brings me further. I still have the same error but at least have managed to decrypt the SSD. When i press help, it shows the following commands:

> alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export false getopts hash help history let local printf pwd read readonly return set shift test times trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait acpid ash awk basename blockdev cat chmod chroot chvt clear cmp cp cut deallocvt deluser devmem df du dumpkmap echo egrep env expr false fbse fgrep find fstrim grep gunzip qzip hostname hwclock ifconfig if kill ln loadfont loadkmap izop mkdir mkfifo mknod mkswap mktemp modinfo more mount mv openvt pidof printf ps pwd readlink reset rm rmdir sed seq setkeycodes sh sleep sort stat static-sh stty switch_root synt tail tee test touch tr true tty umount uname uniq wc wget which yes<

Whoever help with this is a true hero! No way i'll figure this out myself. I hope you're all having a good Easter and staying healthy in these times.

Edit:
So lets approach the issue from a different, probably easier, point of view. I used an Ubuntu 18.04 ISO on usb to boot the computer, but i'm running Ubuntu now on test mode, rather than overwriting the existing encrypted partition that I really need to access, and now can view the unreadable partition on Gparted and on GNOME Disks. It seems very close now to see this solved since I know the password. However, when I enter it in GNOME Disks it gives me error: Error unlocking /dev/sda5: Failed to activate device: operation not permitted (udisks-error-quark, 0)" Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I managed to access the partition on GNOME disks. Seems the password was the issue there. Indeed it was possible to access the drive that way, although I still don't know how to bypass register access failure if it appears again.